How to select a single element from an array contained in MongoDB document using Spring Data?
I am new to MongoDB. I have a collection like:
[
   {
      "_id":"1",
      "travels":[
         {
            "_id":"1"
         },
         {
            "_id":"2"
         },
         {
            "_id":"3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"2",
      "travels":[
         {
            "_id":"4"
         },
         {
            "_id":"5"
         },
         {
            "_id":"6"
         }
      ]
   }
]

My Java model is more or less like this (using public modifiers for simplicity):
public class TravelsDocument<T> {
    @Id
    public String id;
    public List<Travel> travels;
}

public class Travel {
    public String id;
}

All ids in travels arrays are unique. In my Spring application I would like to select a single travel element matching specified id.
I've finally figured out how to do that in MongoDB.
First, I applied a filter:
{travels: {$elemMatch: { _id: 'someId'}}}

and then a projection:
{
   "_id":0,
   "travel":{
      "$arrayElemAt":[
         "$travels",
         {
            "$indexOfArray":[
               "$travels._id",
               "someId"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}

Then I tried to use it in an aggregation:
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
        "{'$match' :{'travels': {$elemMatch: { _id: :#{#id}}}}}",
        "{'$project' :{_id:0,     'travel':{$arrayElemAt: [ '$travels', {$indexOfArray :['$travels._id', :#{#id}]} ] }}}"})
    Mono<Travel> findSingleTravelByTenantAndId(@Param("id") String id);

The issue is that this method doesn't return my Travel object but rather org.bson.Document object. Is there a way to return my custom object using Aggregation annotation? Is this the way to go?

You can try defining a custom object with the required fields, instead of the Document. See this post: How to omit fields while retrieving documents in spring-data-mongodb?

Travel class already has the required fields, I don't want to skip any of them. My problem is that even though returned Document object has the same fields as my Travel they are not cast correctly (I think).
Document{{_id=someId, anotherField=someValue}}
is returned from Mongo, but it seems to be not mapped correctly to my Travel object resulting in
{"id":null, "anotherField": null}

Then the query is not correctly returning the result. What would the result document and its fields look like?

Sorry, in my answer above I used object.toString(). I think it will be more readable with json. When I change the repository method to return Mono<Object> instead or Mono<Travel>, the result looks like: {"_id":"someId", "anotherField":"someValue"}, and these fields values are correct. But when I use Mono<Travel> as the return type, the result looks like: {"_id":null, "anotherField":null}

The final projection stage of the aggregation pipeline would return documents as { travel: { _id: 123 } }. But that's not the structure of your Travel class, it only defines id (which I presume maps to _id). So you need to add a $replaceWith stage: { $replaceWith: "$travel" } OR remove the project stage and instead use replaceWith directly: { $replaceWith: { $arrayElemAt: ["$travels", { $indexOfArray: ["$travels._id", "123"] } ] } } https://mongoplayground.net/p/FZZjLk0-UUm

@nanotasza Can you tell what the actual result (expected output) should like from the example documents in your question?

Thank you @aneroid, this is exactly what I was missing! Worked like a charm.
@prasad_, from my example it would look like: {"_id" : "4"}, if id==4 was matched, rather than {"_id" : null}.

The final projection stage of the aggregation pipeline would return documents as { travel: { _id: 123 } } - note the outer travel field. But that's not the structure of your Travel class, it only defines id (which I presume maps to _id), and probably other fields/members.
So you need to add a $replaceWith stage:
{ $replaceWith: "$travel" }

Or better, remove the project stage and use replaceWith instead:
{
  $replaceWith: {
      "$arrayElemAt":[
         "$travels",
         {
            "$indexOfArray":[
               "$travels._id",
               "someId"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}

So the full pipeline would be:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      travels: { $elemMatch: { _id: "someId" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        "$travels",
        { $indexOfArray: ["$travels._id", "someId"] }
      ]
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

This is a variation of the query. Produces the result for the filter field travels._id value is '4':
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    $match: { 
        "travels._id": '4' 
    } 
},
{ 
    $replaceWith: { 
        $arrayElemAt: [
            { $filter: { input: "$travels", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", '4' ] } } },
            0
        ]
    }
}
])

The output: [ { _id: '4' } ]
